# Typescript: Gather all string literals of a property of an array of objects

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make something typesafe and I'm not 100% sure if it's possible:

If I have an array of "services", where a `Service` is defined as:

```
interface Service {
  id: string;
  dependencies?: [string] // refs to others Service.id's
}
```

Is there a way to make the `dependencies` array typesafe? To illustrate:

```
import { Service } from './service.ts';

const services: Service[] = [
  {
    id: "authors",
  },
  {
    id: "comments",
  }
  {
    id: "posts",
    dependencies: [] // <-- type this as `Array<"authors | "comments">`
  }
]
```

Comment: You can declare dependencies as an array of enums. Just extract ids to separate enum. If you need unique values in the array then declare it as Set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) to do something like this:

```
type RawType = "authors" | "comments";
type RawId = { id : RawType };
type Posts = {
  id: "posts";
  dependencies: RawType[];
}

type Service = RawId | Posts;

// then you can declare an array of Service
const services: Service[] = [
  {
    id: "authors",
  },
  {
    id: "comments",
  },
  {
    id: "posts",
    dependencies: [],
  }
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASghgdwCrmgXigIjgV2ACwHsAnAZ0ygB8sBjQgW3ogDthyBuAWAChRJZEASQAmUDAG8oAS1EAuAclRQAvl15KACoVJsxUcTyjTh8zGG1tMao8IiRmt5jSkRS8+IsgBtALprlPDx80ADKEMQAblI06AoiVFBaOqRqPAD0aVAELFAghDhQNHDMULY0ADZwxNDFUFXEcCBQhABmUGGR0RA8dMw6UKThUTFu7UNdvnpehvozRjKmuAQk5AA0M8rr3EYG20bGpnSMLJZbRpszu-sHWObJmGf7tvaOzq7yvo8B3H5AA)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit ugly - to ensure that the id is listed in the array of the dependnecies, you can do the following:

```
type Id = 'id1' | 'id2' | 'id3'
type Obj<CurrentId extends Id> = {
  id: CurrentId
  dependencies: Exclude<Id, CurrentId>[]
}

const obj: <CurrentId extends Id>(obj: Obj<CurrentId>) => Obj<CurrentId> = obj => obj

const array = [
  obj({
    id: 'id1',
    dependencies: [], // compiled
  }),
  obj({
    id: 'id2',
    dependencies: ['id1'], // compiled
  }),
  obj({
    id: 'id3',
    dependencies: ['id3'], // compilation error
  }),
  obj({
    id: 'id3', // note: compiled even when there are multiple objects with the same Id
    dependencies: [],
  }),
]
```